# CIVIC 07 - Passenger side low beam and parking lights don't work

Tags: civic

The passenger side parking and low beam doesn't work. Both high beams work. Any ideas?

Comment: Asak! Did you try changing the bulbs? T10 (parking), H4 (high/low beam)

Comment: No, will do it tomorrow.. it's late night now.. Are T10 and H4 fuses?

Comment: @NumairAidroos was curious that both bulbs could go off at the same time...? Could it be the fuse?

Comment: Those are bulb standards, I listed. You start with the bulbs, we'll narrow it down either to the holder, wiring, or a fuse/relay. At this point it could be anything.

Comment: @NumairAidroos it was the bulbs.Thanks for your help!

Comment: Perfect. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check the fuses, not likely the bulbs blew at the same time, to check, just replace with another fuse of something that you know is working, and see if the lights come on. If not, try replacing the bulbs!

Comment: I found out it was the bulbs. Thanks for your answer anyways!

Comment: Good it worked out.